# What is the word for fear of fear?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, phobias

What is the word for fear of fear?

I thought this would be easy to find, recall, or previously asked, but I've looked around and couldn't find it ([phobia list](http://phobialist.com/)).

It is simply phobiaphobia? Or phobophobia?

Comment: The fear of fear frightens me.  Unfortunately, recursion makes me dreadfully nervous too.

Comment: @Malvolio - then do not go to [this reference](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217500/what-is-the-word-for-fear-of-fear).

Comment: It turns out that phobophobia is on the [phobia list](http://phobialist.com/). Maybe that makes this General Reference?

Comment: ....fearception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct - the word for this is [phobophobia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phobophobia)

Comment: And the word for fear of fear of fear is of course *phobophobophobia*. And...